# How to send parameters from PHP to Backbone in external file.js

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, default-value

I'm tring to write my first `Backbone.js app` inside my `CakePHP app` and trying to avoid writing my app in the page directly but to do it on a specific file stored in `js/backbone/app.js` where I'll put the Backbone app.

My first test was made by writing the app inside the page just to make some test, the problem is that the Model app has default values which came from php data.

Here is the example **without** including the `app.js`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My app test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/backbone/backbone.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/underscore.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var Status = {
            Models: {},
            Collections: {},
            Views: {},
            Templates:{}
        }
        Status.Models.Message = Backbone.Model.extend({
            defaults:{
                icon:"<?php echo $this->App->icon('default-icon-name');?>",
                type:"warning",
                title:"<?php echo __('Default title'); ?>",
                message:"<?php echo __('Default status message text'); ?>"
            },
            initialize:function () {
                console.log("Backbone console message from initialize event");
            }
        });
        // here the rest of the app
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        here is the app!
    </body>
</html>
```

Now I've moved the app inside `js/backbone/app.js` and I'm not sure how is the easiest way to pass the default parameters of the Model from the page inside my `app.js`.

Here is the example **where I've put** all the Backbone app inside the `app.js`:

```
$(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://site.com/json/default_app"
    }).done(function(data) {
        var Status = {
            Models: {},
            Collections: {},
            Views: {},
            Templates:{}
        }
        Status.Models.Message = Backbone.Model.extend({
            defaults:data,
            initialize:function () {
                console.log("Backbone console message from initialize event");
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Should i put my app for example inside the document ready of `jQuery`? I hope not, this would force me to create a specific `Controller` inside my `CakePHP` app that would be very annoying to keep up to date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you basically have two options:

1. You can PHP-ify your JS files.  I'm no PHP expert, so I can't tell you the particulars of how you do this, but essentially there is some setting somewhere you can modify to tell PHP to process your *.js files.  If you do this, then you can stick whatever PHP logic you want in to `app.js` (or any other JS file).

   However this approach strongly couples your PHP and your JS code, and that's generally regarded as a bad idea (for the same reason that heavily mixing your PHP and your HTML is considered bad practice).  Therefore, I'd recommend ...
2. You can write the PHP parts out in to variables on your PHP pages, then reference those variables in your JS files.

For example in your PHP file you can do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var YOUR_APP = {};
YOUR_APP.MESSAGE = {};
YOUR_APP.MESSAGE.ICON_SRC = "<?php echo $this->App->icon('default-icon-name');?>";
YOUR_APP.MESSAGE.TITLE = "<?php echo __('Default title'); ?>";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
```

and then in `app.js` you can just do:

```
Status.Models.Message = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        icon: YOUR_APP.MESSAGE.ICON_SRC,
        title: YOUR_APP.MESSAGE.TITLE,
    },
    initialize:function () {
        console.log("Backbone console message from initialize event");
    }
});
```

Because of the ordering of the `<script>` tags, you don't need any onDOMReady wrappings.

Comment: Also, you might want to check out http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-bootstrap (it's not *exactly* the same as what you're trying to do, but it's in the same vein).